# subtracting int gives different result than addition

Tags: javascript, arrays, p5.js, cellular-automata

(I don't mean that subtracting gives a different mathematical result than addition-that's obvious)
I'm trying to make a particle simulator game, and I ran into a weird phenomenon. (I'm using javascript with javap5.js). In the draw function, I have a function that test if the space below a particle is empty, and if it is, it moves down by one pixel(or adding one to the result-that's where the addition is) The only issue is, instead of a gradual change when going down, it INSTANTLY goes to the bottom of the screen. When I use subtraction instead(so gravity is up) it behaves as expected and goes up gradually.
Here's the function I'm talking about(game is the array of particles)-

```
function updateParticles() {
  for(var i = 0; i<250; i++) {
    for(var i2 = 0; i2<250; i2++) {
      if(game[i][i2] == 1) {
        if(game[i][i2+1] == 0) {
          game[i][i2]=0;
          game[i][i2+1]=1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and here is the whole thing(jsfiddle)-
https://jsfiddle.net/gwood5901/trm6xLv8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `for` loops are going from left to right, top to bottom. Here's a simplified model of what is happening:

```
i = 0;
[ 1 ] <-- Is this a one?
[ 0 ] <-- And is this a zero?
[ 0 ]

YES
SWAP

[ 0 ] <-- prev 1
[ 1 ] <-- prev 0
[ 0 ]

i = 1;
[ 0 ] 
[ 1 ] <-- Is this a one?
[ 0 ] <-- And is this a zero?

YES
SWAP
[ 0 ]
[ 0 ] <-- prev 1
[ 1 ] <-- prev 0
```

And that all happens at once in one call of the function.

With the subtraction:

```
i = 0;
[ 0 ] <-- Is this a zero?
[ 0 ] <-- And is this a one?
[ 1 ]

NO
DO NOTHING

i = 1;
[ 0 ] 
[ 0 ] <-- Is this a zero?
[ 1 ] <-- And is this a one?

YES
SWAP
[ 0 ]
[ 1 ] <-- prev 0
[ 0 ] <-- prev 1
```

And on the second function call:

```
i = 0;
[ 0 ] <-- Is this a zero?
[ 1 ] <-- And is this a one?
[ 0 ]

YES
SWAP

[ 1 ] <-- prev 0
[ 0 ] <-- prev 1
[ 0 ] 

i = 1;
[ 1 ]
[ 0 ] <-- Is this a zero?
[ 0 ] <-- And is this a one?

NO
DO NOTHING
```

This can be fixed two ways: a buffer or just traversing the array backwards.

Here's the simple way of just traversing the array backwards:

```js
function  {
  for(var i = 250-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for(var i2 = 250-2; i2 >= 0; i2--) {
      if(game[i][i2] == 1) {
        if(game[i][i2+1] == 0) {
          game[i][i2]=0;
          game[i][i2+1]=1;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle with the `updateParticles()` function changed to this: https://jsfiddle.net/Lhqgujxt/